# Transparent actionBar and statusBar in Android lollipop

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to create this interface :

[image]

And here is my actual result :

[image]

- The status bar is well transparent and we see my image as background : OK
- The action bar is not transparent : NOK

Here is the code of my theme that I use for this activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="MaterialAppDetailTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- enable window content transitions -->
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

        <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
            @transition/change_image_transform</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
            @transition/change_image_transform</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you using actionbar or toolbar?

Comment: @PedroOliveira actionBar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change your toolbar color to transparent like this:

```
mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

You can change it's background on the XML too:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Or if you're using ActionBar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Use `getActionBar()` if you're not using `ActionBarActivity`

Result:

[image]

Comment: He needs to add additional `marginTop` to the size of the status bar, if he uses `fitSystemWindow` in theme/layout xml. Otherwise, status bar bottom line will be on the navigation icon, which doesn't look good.

Comment: I suppose he got that covered since the only problem he described was the fact that his actionbar was not transparent. The current screen was just something I built just to show the effect.

Comment: Yep, just as precaution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For API that >= 21, add to theme these lines of code

`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Don't forget to add

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`