# How to make appBar and statusBar transparent

Tags: android-actionbar, statusbar

I want my home page of my app to look like the pictures seen in this link [Transparent actionBar and statusBar in Android lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327081/transparent-actionbar-and-statusbar-in-android-lollipop)

How can I do this?

Comment: yoshatabi did you follow the code that was provided? and if so, did it work or you ran into an error? Please be specific about what you need, what you tried and where you got stuck

Comment: I would be able to do. I tried to follow it but I didn't know where exactly to put the code. Like in which xml's etc. I put the one of them in my main java class but it gave me a few declaration errors

Comment: okay okay, well I'm an iOS guy so I can't help you with that, but, you can edit your question now and put those details, the more the better