# Action bar Transparent in pre Lollipop devices

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

So I'm done with my app and doing final tests. On Android 5.0+ it runs fine, but on pre Lollipop devices i get strange bug.

At first, action bar was not visible on activities with `ScrollView` and I fixed it by putting `ScrollView` inside of `RelativeLayout`. But that solves only half of the problem. `Action bar` color is transparent and I can tell that because background color in my activities is `#f2f2f2` and text on `Action bar` is white.

I see action bar title, back button and all images I put in action bar, but just can't set the color of it to `ColorPrimary` which is material light blue.

Here's the ACTIVITY code (not content)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.VjezbeTricepsTricepsEkstenzijaKablovima">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:elevation="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_vjezbe_triceps_triceps_ekstenzija_kablovima" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's java file where i declare

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vjezbe_triceps_triceps_ekstenzija_kablovima);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure about set action bar transparent on lollipop backwards, please paste your error to give some relevant information

Comment: There's no error, I just want action bar color to be blue like it is on Lilipop and Marshmallow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327081/transparent-actionbar-and-statusbar-in-android-lollipop HOPE IT HELPS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/** In your xml,color/background ,change according to your Requirement  **/

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
    android:background="@color/appbarColor">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/place_order"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/appbar_txt_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

/** In your java file **/

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#617191"));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! The line toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#617191")); was all I needed!